# Check number of argument repeated

Tags: javascript

There is a website that is updated all the time. I wan't to take from the website the number of the argument: "[" repeat and print it in var - 1.
For example: [ Is shown 6 times the var will be 5 ( 6-1=5).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wan't to take from the website the number of the argument: "["
>   repeat and print it in var - 1.

`[` is not an argument and you weren't specific from where you would want to get the number of `[` other than "THE WEBSITE"

```js
console.log('L[orem i[psum [ dolor s[it amet['.match(/\[/g).length - 1);
```

Comment: I forgot to tell you this is json file. http://173.249.42.182:30120/players.json this is the "Website"